# Dynamic Memory Allocation in C ( return value 3221225477 & Segmentation fault: 11 )

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

Can anyone explain what is the wrong of the code below? İf I give the "line" variable as 1,2,3 or 4, it runs correctly. But after 4 it just shows a count of row correctly, the count of columns is not correct.

output of dev-c/c++ on windows >> "return value 3221225477"

output of gcc on mac >> "Segmentation fault: 11"

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){

int **matris;
int size;
int i, j;

printf( "Size >> " );
scanf( "%d", &size );

matris = (int **)malloc( size * sizeof(int) );

if( matris == NULL )
    printf( "It's required more memory'!" );

for( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
    matris[i] = malloc( size * sizeof(int) );
    if( matris[i] == NULL )
        printf( "It's required more memory'!!" );
}

for( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
    for( j = 0; j < size; j++ ){    
        matris[i][j]=i+1;
        printf( "%d ", matris[i][j] );
    }
    printf( "\n" );
}


for( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
    free( matris[i] );
}

free( matris );

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(int **)malloc( size * sizeof(int) );` looks wrong, it should be `sizeof(int*)`

Comment: `matris = (int **)malloc( size * sizeof(int) );` You should not cast the return value of `malloc` in C. And you do not allocate correct size. `matrix` points to `int*`, not `int`.

Comment: Run it in gdb and it will tell you exactly what the issue is.

Comment: Others have already posted the solution. Try printing the sizes of ints vs int pointer with `printf("int: %zu, ptr: %zu", sizeof(int), sizeof(int*));`. On an x86_64/AMD64 machine, that gives me `int: 4, ptr: 8`. That's why your code crashes.

Comment: Just replace all of the icky, segmented bugginess with `int (*matris)[j] = malloc(sizeof(int[size][size]));` ... `free(matris);`.

Comment: 3221225477 = 0xC0000005. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

```
matris = (int **)malloc( size * sizeof(int) );
```

with especially `( size * sizeof(int) )` is wrong. You need to allocate memory for objects of type `int*`(pointer to `int`), not `int`.

This is a problem if `sizeof(int) < sizeof(int*)` on your implementation -> Translated: The size of an object of type pointer to `int` is bigger than the size of an object of type `int`, which is quite common.

Then you get a segmentation fault, because you access memory beyond the bounds of the pointer array `matris` in the following code.

Use:

```
matris = malloc ( sizeof(int*) * size );
```

or even better

```
matris = malloc ( sizeof(*matris) * size );
```

---

Side Notes:

- You don't need to cast the return of `malloc()`. The returned pointer is automatically aligned. [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/)
- `sizeof(*matris)` requires less maintenance and is more safe if the type of `matris` and the pointed objects changes.
- Set the `sizeof` operation first to ensure `size_t` arithmetic, since `size` is of type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

The line `matris = (int **)malloc( size * sizeof(int) );` is incorrect as you want to create an array of int pointers and not of int. Changing the `int` to `int*` works.

Comment: `malloc( size * sizeof(int) );` actually creates an array of `int` and the OP wants an array of int pointers. You probably meant the other way around?

Comment: Hey @Lundin, I meant the other way, thanks for correcting.